# Javascript Creating a Turkish Sluggable

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to convert Turkish characters to readable slug. But it fails with undefined...

What is the problem here?

Html

```
<div id="converter">Fıstıkçı Şahap Çık Dışarı Dağlarda Oyna</div>
```

Js:

```
String.prototype.sluggable = function(){
    var string = this;
    var letters = {
        "İ": "i",
        "I": "i",
        "ı": "i",
        "Ş": "s",
        "ş": "s",
        "Ğ": "g",
        "ğ": "g",
        "Ü": "u",
        "ü": "u",
        "Ö": "o",
        "ö": "o",
        "Ç": "c",
        "ç": "c"
    };

    string = string.replace(/([İIıŞşĞğÜüÇçÖö])+/g, function(letter){ return letters[letter]; });
    return string.toLowerCase().replace(/([^a-zA-Z0-9])+/g, '_');
}

var $text = $('#converter').text();
$('#converter').text($text.sluggable());
```

Demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/Fr8Nq/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your regular expression to the following:

```
/[İIıŞşĞğÜüÇçÖö]/g
```

You don't need to match the sequence of characters but replace them individually.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/Fr8Nq/1/

Comment: You are my savior. Twice today :)